# Kubernetes and Socket.io 404 error - works locally but not after applying to kubernetes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, kubernetes, websocket

Apologies in advance for such a long question, I just want to make sure I cover everything...

I have a react application that is supposed to connect to a socket being run in a service that I have deployed to kubernetes. The service runs and works fine. I am able to make requests without any issue but I cannot connect to the websocket running in the same service.

I am able to connect to the websocket when I run the service locally and use the locahost uri.

My express service's server.ts file looks like:

```
import "dotenv/config";
import * as packageJson from "./package.json"

import service from "./lib/service";
const io = require("socket.io");

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

const server = service.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.info(`Server up and running on ${PORT}...`);
  console.info(`Environment = ${process.env.NODE_ENV}...`);
  console.info(`Service Version = ${packageJson.version}...`);
});

export const socket = io(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

socket.on('connection', function(skt) {
  console.log('User Socket Connected');
  socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log(`${skt.id} User disconnected.`));
});

export default service;
```

When I run this, `PORT` is set to 8088, and access-control-allow-origin is set to `*`. And note that I'm using a rabbitmq cluster that is deployed to Kubernetes, it is the same uri for the rabbit connection when I run locally. Rabbitmq is NOT running on my local machine, so I know it's not an issue with my rabbit deployment, it has to be something I'm doing wrong in connecting to the socket.

When I run the service locally, I'm able to connect in the react application with the following:

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io("ws://localhost:8088", { path: "/socket.io" });
```

And I see the "User Socket Connected" message and it all works as I expect.

When I deploy the service to Kubernetes though, I'm having some issues figuring out how to connect to the socket.

My Kubernetes Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8088
  selector:
    app: my-service
```

My deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: project
          image: my-private-registry.com
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8088
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: mySecret
```

And finally, my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true" // Just added this to see if it helped
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*" // Just added this to see if it helped
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH // Just added this to see if it helped
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my.host.com
      secretName: my-service-tls
  rules:
    - host: "my.host.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/project"
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I can connect to the service fine and get data, post data, etc. but I cannot connect to the websocket, I get either 404 or cors errors.

Since the service is running on my.host.com/project, I assume that the socket is at the same uri. So I try to connect with:

```
const socket = io("ws://my.host.com", { path: "/project/socket.io" });
```

and also using wss://

```
const socket = io("wss://my.host.com", { path: "/project/socket.io" });
```

and I have an error being logged in the console:

```
socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});
```

both result in

```
polling-xhr.js?d33e:198 GET https://my.host.com/project/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NjWQ8Tc 404
websocket.ts?25e3:14 connect_error due to xhr poll error
```

I have tried all of the following and none of them work:

```
const socket = io("ws://my.host.com", { path: "/socket.io" });
const socket = io("wss://my.host.com", { path: "/socket.io" });
const socket = io("ws://my.host.com", { path: "/project" });
const socket = io("wss://my.host.com", { path: "/project" });
const socket = io("ws://my.host.com", { path: "/" });
const socket = io("wss://my.host.com", { path: "/" });
const socket = io("ws://my.host.com");
const socket = io("wss://my.host.com");
```

Again, this works when the service is run locally, so I must have missed something and any help would be extremely appreciated.

Is there a way to go on the Kubernetes pod and find where rabbit is being broadcast to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case somebody stumbles on this in the future and wants to know how to fix it, it turns out it was a really dumb mistake on my part..

In:

```
export const socket = io(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  },
});
```

I just needed to add `path: "/project/socket.io"` to the socket options, which makes sense.

And then if anybody happens to run into the issue that followed, I was getting a 400 error on the post to the websocket polling so I set `transports: [ "websocket" ]` in my socket.io-client options and that seemed to fix it. The socket is now working and I can finally move on!